# How to change IP Location information?

Tags: ip

How to change IP Location information?

Hello,

When viewing website whois through `whois.domaintools.com`, under the *Server Stats* tab, there is the IP Location information and looks like this:

```
IP Location: - Netherlands - Dedicated/collocated/various Hosting Customers
```

What to do to change the IP Location information after the word `Netherlands`?

Answer (score 7):

You do not. The information comes from the AS information, and you do not control that - your hoster does (and an AS - Autonomous System - has  LOT of ip addresses).

Whois indicates who owns the network and whatever information they want to be there.

Comment: i entirely disagrees with @TomTom i really don't know why he is saying what he is saying...people change that information very very well http://whois.domaintools.com/kbeezie.com check server stats tab and see
http://whois.domaintools.com/nairaland.com check server stats tab and see so tell me TomTom was that by magic?

Comment: @grant Did you notice that the two servers have different IP addresses? The mapping is done in IP address using a GeoIP database most likely.

Comment: on top, domain whois gives the DOMAIN registration location, NOT th IP - contrary to popular believe a domain has no intrinsic relation to an IP address. THe question is not about domains but about ip addresses. Interesting enough the domain and the ip location can be different (I live ni the US, the hoster is in thailand - the IP will show and belon to thailand).